# Is there a way to put a line-break without having to put <br> in all these lines?

Tags: html, css

Also, without having to create another div for that.(Only with CSS and HTML).

I wanna make it look like this
[image] not [image: like this one]

style:

```css
#adjust {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 36%;
  text-align: left;
/*  top: -1000px; */
}
```

```html
<ul id="adjust">
  <li><strong>1914</strong> - Born in Cresco, Iowa</li>
  <li><strong>1933</strong> - Leaves his family's farm to attend the University of Minnesota, thanks to a Depression era program known as the "National Youth Administration"</li>
  <li><strong>1935</strong> - Has to stop school and save up more money. Works in the Civilian Conservation Corps, helping starving Americans. "I saw how food changed them", he said. "All of this left scars on me."</li>
  <li><strong>1937</strong> - Finishes university and takes a job in the US Forestry Service</li>
  <li><strong>1938</strong> - Marries wife of 69 years Margret Gibson. Gets laid off due to budget cuts. Inspired by Elvin Charles Stakman, he returns to school study under Stakman, who teaches him about breeding pest-resistent plants.</li>
  <li><strong>1941</strong> - Tries to enroll in the military after the Pearl Harbor attack, but is rejected. Instead, the military asked his lab to work on waterproof glue, DDT to control malaria, disenfectants, and other applied science.</li>
  <li><strong>1942</strong> - Receives a Ph.D. in Genetics and Plant Pathology</li>
  <li><strong>1944</strong> - Rejects a 100% salary increase from Dupont, leaves behind his pregnant wife, and flies to Mexico to head a new plant pathology program. Over the next 16 years, his team breeds 6,000 different strains of disease resistent wheat
    - including different varieties for each major climate on Earth.</li>
  <li><strong>1945</strong> - Discovers a way to grown wheat twice each season, doubling wheat yields</li>
  <li><strong>1953</strong> - crosses a short, sturdy dwarf breed of wheat with a high-yeidling American breed, creating a strain that responds well to fertalizer. It goes on to provide 95% of Mexico's wheat.</li>
  <li><strong>1962</strong> - Visits Delhi and brings his high-yielding strains of wheat to the Indian subcontinent in time to help mitigate mass starvation due to a rapidly expanding population</li>
  <li><strong>1970</strong> - receives the Nobel Peace Prize</li>
  <li><strong>1983</strong> - helps seven African countries dramatically increase their maize and sorghum yields</li>
  <li><strong>1984</strong> - becomes a distinguished professor at Texas A&M University</li>
  <li><strong>2005</strong> - states "we will have to double the world food supply by 2050." Argues that genetically modified crops are the only way we can meet the demand, as we run out of arable land. Says that GM crops are not inherently dangerous because
    "we've been genetically modifying plants and animals for a long time. Long before we called it science, people were selecting the best breeds."</li>
  <li><strong>2009</strong> - dies at the age of 95.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet but had to comment out the -1000 - please adjust the sniippet

Comment: How about a definition list?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19254411/1531971 (Or you need to tell us why not.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use margin?

Style:

```
#adjust li {
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not exatcly what I want.. you see that the line breaks at "Minnesota,"? That's what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin to the bottom of each `<li>` element with the following CSS:

```
li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: That's not exatcly what I want.. you see that the line breaks at "Minnesota,"? That's what I mean...

Comment: @DominickTorres oooh i understand. Are the breaks arbitrary? Why after minnesota for example? Or is it a width thing?

Comment: It's just like the first image.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap it in a container that has a set width(smaller than the existing one) so it breaks the line earlier. Or you could just set the width for the `ul`.

[JSFiddle example](//jsfiddle.net/nxw35vjL/2/)

`#adjust {width: 50%}` Or use different values and units
then add some margin `#adjust li {margin-bottom: 10px;}`

If you want it to look nicer, also try `#adjust {text-align: justify}`

Answer (score 0):

First move the title ahead with: padding-left: 10px;
then you can use a margin-bottom like this for each paragraphe:

```css
#adjust {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 36%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  /*  top: -1000px; */
}
```

Good luck